# Refresh fragment of ViewPager from parent activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

My 4 fragments in **ViewPager** have one common button from parent activity that opens a dialog and should refresh **ListViews** in these 4 fragments. I tried using static adapters but that didn't work. Now I'm trying to use broadcast but still I won't see my adapter from outer **broadcast receiver**. Please help.

Comment: Share some code

Comment: Share you PagerAdapter class code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had same requirement i did following :- 
1. Extend pagerAdapter with FragmentStatePagerAdapter
2. Implement below in your pagerAdapter class

```
 @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
```

3. then when ever you refresh just call -

> notifyDataSetChanged();

on adapter.

you can get your adapter from your viewpager as below:

> viewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();

here viewpager is reference of my viewpager.

Comment: I tried this way but application is getting a lag and turns off on refresh. :/

Comment: Ahh I wrote getItemPosition not properly, it works great, thanks :D!

Comment: Man, I searched the web through for this and couldn't find such answer, reallyyyyy, upvote anyone that comes here please :)

Answer (score 0):

add your 4 lists to a map with separate key(1,2,3,4).

```
if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 0){
// show list items with key 1
}else if(viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 1){
//show list items with key 2
}else if(....)
```

now put a listener and call it on button click.

Comment: I think this won't work properly because one fragment in a viewpager on the right side can be actually initialized and I wanted to refresh the fragment that is not even shown. I posted an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Like always, I've been trying do something for a few days and when I posted it here, I found a thing I've done wrong :D

So, How do I do that:

In each of a child fragments I create a broadcast receiver

```
    receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context contextBroadcast, Intent intent) {
            createListView(listView, context);
        }
    };

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("com.cukrzyca.DISMISS");
    context.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

And it turns out you have to prepare IntentFilter well, that's what I've done wrong. Method createListView just refreshes the listView, and dialog dismisses in parent activity I just send broadcast:

```
public void broadcastDismiss() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("com.cukrzyca.DISMISS");
    getContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```